# Average of points within range of a point using FME without buffering?

Tags: fme-form, spatial-join

There are a series of reference points along a track and another set of observation points nearby with an observed value as an attribute. For each reference point it is necessary to find the average of the attribute of all observation points that are within some distance (e.g. 20 meters).

Ideally this would be done without buffering and the number of related points is also recorded.

Comment: Have you tried linear referencing?

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you want to use a bufferer?

A possible solution is to use a NeighborFinder with "generate list" checked, to get a list of all the attributes of elements within a certain range.
Average them by using a list summer and a list element counter.

Be sure to reproject them in a coordinate system that has meters.

[image]